# BLE Scan not finding BLE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have 3 Android device, Samsung Galaxy S3 phone, Samsung Tab4 and Verizon OEM Tablet. The Verizon OEM tablet doesn't support BLE, API 17. I installed "BLE Device Scan" from the android developers website and run it on the Galaxy S3. It only shows the Verizon Tablet as the found device. When I run the same app on the Samsung Tab4, it only shows the Galaxy S3 as the found device. If I simply look at the bluetooth settings on the Galaxy S3, it shows both the Verizon and Samsung Tablets and similarly, when I look at the Bluetooth settings on the Samsung Tab4, it shows the Galaxy S3 and Verizon Tablet as nearby Bluetooth devices. But neither Galaxy S3 nor Samsung Tab4 are ever shown during BLE scan.

Any suggestions on what I should try next?

Thank You,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Devices can not be found using BLE scanning. Try finding ibeacons, or other BLE clients.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are not showing up is because the current api for ble support only the central role.
meaning you can scan only for ble devices that are ble advertising. the current api doesn't let you "adveritse".